# Write a scheme that returns a list of even numbers

Tags: list, scheme, lisp

Write a Scheme function that returns the list of even numbers in a given list of integer numbers.The list may not be simple,nested lists can occur and you need to find the even numbers inside those.

(DEFINE (evenlist numberlist)
using this as a body and getting the result sth like this
(DEFINE (evenlist numberlist)
Result:(2 4 6 4)

```
(define (evenlist numberlist)
  (cond
    ((null? numberlist) '())
    (else(not (= 0 (modulo (numberlist) 2))(evenlist(car numberlist))))
    ))
```

this is what i have done , i am new to lisp so dont blame me :(

Comment: And what have you tried so far? please post your scheme implementation, pointing the parts where you're having trouble

Comment: (define (evenlist numberlist)
  (cond
    ((null? numberlist) '())
    (else(not (= 0 (modulo (numberlist) 2))(evenlist(car numberlist))))
    )) tried this but didnt work

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code, not as a comment

Comment: sorry fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do a bit more of work if the input list is an arbitrarily nested list of lists. This is the standard template to process such lists (cases: empty list, non-list or a list of lists), plus additional logic to flatten the result (that's why `append` is used here):

```
(define (evenlist numberlist)
  (cond ((null? numberlist) '())
        ((not (pair? numberlist))
         (if (even? numberlist) (list numberlist) '()))
        (else
         (append (evenlist (car numberlist))
                 (evenlist (cdr numberlist))))))
```

Comment: ok but before that i need to define the pair function because it outputs it as an error

Comment: `pair?` is a Scheme primitive, it should be part of your interpreter. Try changing to a different, more advanced language - or see if `list?` or something equivalent is defined in your scheme, and replace it.

Comment: our teacher told us that we can use only intermediate languange  and i changed the pair? into cons? and it outputs (list 2 4) . I think that is correct

Comment: if i replace the pair? for list? or cons? it gives me te same result (list 2 4)